# How to write a play-json Reads for Map[(Int, Int), A]?

Tags: scala, play-json

I want to deserialize this json, which represents a rack that is a 5x5 playing field and contains one tile at position (1,2):

```
{
  "rows" : 5,
  "cols" : 5,
  "tiles" : [ {
    "row" : 1,
    "col" : 2,
    "tile" : {
      "number" : 3
    }
  } ]
}
```

So my case classes are:

```scala
case class Tile(number: Int)
case class Rack(rows: Int, cols: Int, tiles: Map[(Int, Int), Tile])
```

I tried to write a Reads for the class rack:

```scala
implicit val tileWrites = Json.writes[Tile]
implicit val tileReads = Json.reads[Tile]

implicit val reads: Reads[Rack] = (
    (__ \ "rows").read[Int] and
      (__ \ "cols").read[Int] and
      (__ \ "tiles").read[Map[(Int, Int), Tile]]
  ) (Rack.apply _)
```

But i got this error:

```
Error:(50, 26) No Json deserializer found for type Map[(Int, Int),de.htwg.se.rummi.model.model.Tile]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
      (__ \ "tiles").read[Map[(Int, Int), Tile]]
```

Can someone explain how I write a Reads for Map[(Int, Int), Tile]?

Comment: You first need to define what is the expected JSON representation, considering that `(Int, Int)` is not something usable as-is for JSON key (which only accept `String`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend defining a custom `Reads` instance for common types like `Map`. Instead I would recommend defining a custom type for the tiles and implement a `Reads` for that. The advantage is that you can place the `Reads` instance in the companion object and the compiler will always find the correct instance without you having to import anything.

```
case class Tiles(tiles: Map[(Int, Int), Tile])
```

Now you can define a `Reads` instance for `Tiles` in the companion object:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

object Tiles {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Tiles] =
    Reads.list {
      (
        (__ \ "row").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "col").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "tile").read[Tile]
      ) { (row, col, tile) => ((row, col), tile) }
    }.map(tuples => Tiles(tuples.toMap))
}
```